# Getting Cannot use import statement outside a module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am trying to create a GraphQLServer using node.js. below is my server.js file but when i run  "node server.js"  command then it's showing "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

```
import { GraphQLServer } from 'graphql-yoga';
import schema from './schema';
const server = new GraphQLServer({ schema });
```

some articles suggested to use  `<script type="module"></script>` but not working in my case.

i have installed following npm commands:-

```
1.Npm init -y
2.npm add graphql-yoga
3.npm install graphql-tools lodash.merge
```

Comment: after npm install esm ,working for me